# How to make dialog without title bar and do not show it in task bar & task manager

Tags: windows, user-interface, c++-cli

I am using CLI to do some Windows GUI work, one requirement is to make the dialog without title bar, and do not show it in the task bar & task manager (do not show it in the Application tab of task manager but OK to show the process in "Processes" tag). I know that there is an enum to do either of this job:

```
// Do not show title bar.
System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;  

// Do not show it in task.
System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedToolWindow;  bar & task manager
```

but how to do both? I tried

```
this->FormBorderStyle = 
    System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedToolWindow | 
    System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
```

or

```
this->FormBorderStyle = 
    System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedToolWindow + 
    System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
```

but the effect is the same as System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedToolWindow

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: NEGATIVE ONE Tagged `c#` and `command-line-interface` but about neither.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide winform in TaskManager application tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232291/is-it-possible-to-hide-winform-in-taskmanager-application-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ShowInTaskbar` property to `false` to hide the form from the taskbar and the other one to remove the border.

Comment: Thanks. Forget to mention that I've already set ShowInTaskbar to false. The point is if I set showInTaskBar to false and style to FormBorderStyle::None, then it will be in the task manager; if I set showInTaskBar to false and style to System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedToolWindow, it will show the title bar.