# How to make WinForm run in background / hide it from TaskManager/Apps

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

What I want to achieve is to hide my program in [Processes/Apps] area. It can be shown in [Background processes] area. I've noticed some programs having this ability like Chrome and [Gitfy](https://github.com/manosim/gitify).

To be precise, I'm trying to make a tray-only winform program, which should be recognized as "background process". But all I tried just make it hidden from Taskbar.

[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232291/is-it-possible-to-hide-winform-in-taskmanager-application-tab) do hide, but it leaves a window titlebar on desktop (which actually is a tool window). So maybe we can work on this and hide that window :/

Comment: What's wrong with `this.Hide();`?

Comment: Updated answer. It should do what you need it to now.

Comment: Why do you need your application to show up in a particular place in some other application (TaskManager)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very thanks to Andy's answer and after a few tests I found the real problem is WinForm will call `Show()` after Form's constructor. That's why my `Hide()` in constructor not works. Then I moved it to `OnLoad` and everything worked out well.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Hide();
}
```

Don't need `CreateParams`, neither `FormBorderStyle.None`.